# Zend2 navigation global to layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a CategoryController with a fetchSingle (return 1 record) and fetchAll (returns all) method from dbase.

Now i want to reuse de fetchall method for a Navigation.

What's the best approach?

Following code:

Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
    /*
     * Category Table
     */
            'CategoryTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                return new TableGateway('category', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'CategoryTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('CategoryTableGateway');
                $table = new Model\CategoryTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

CategoryController:

```
namespace Front\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class CategoryController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $categoryTable;

function indexAction() {
    //$slug = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('slug');

    $this->layout()->setVariable('metatitle', 'title1');
    $this->layout()->setVariable('metadescription', 'description2');
    $this->layout()->setVariable('metakeywords', 'keywords3');

    return new ViewModel(array(
    'category' => $this->getCategories(),
    ));

}

public function getCategory( $slug ){
    return $this->getTable()->getCategory($slug);
}

public function getCategories(){
    return $this->getTable()->getCategories();
}

public function getTable()
{
    if (!$this->categoryTable) {
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $this->categoryTable = $sm->get('CategoryTable');
    }
    return $this->categoryTable;
}
}
```

CategoryModel:

```
namespace Front\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class CategoryTable {

protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;        
}

public function getCategory($slug)
{        
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(array('name' => $slug));
    $resultSet = $resultSet->toArray();
    return $resultSet[0];
}

public function getCategories()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    $resultSet = $resultSet->toArray();
    return $resultSet;
}

}
```

Comment: You want for example all categories listed at every page, or list all these categories at some specified pages, using Zend\Navigation?

Comment: @JurianSluiman Hi Jurian, yes, i have a dbtable category and i want to make a navigation. I saw you can make one based on navigation array in the config but i want to pull it from the dbase. I already have a category class working, now i want to make een instance into the navigation controller and display this into the layout.phtml

Comment: @JurianSluiman, thnx for your reply! Looks good, only one thing i don't understand is the repositry. Is this the same as my CategoryModel which i already have or is a repositry different. Can you give an example or an explanation?

Comment: My point with the repository/controller: it is not the responsibility for the controller to fetch data from a data store. So `fetchSingle` and `fetchAll` are senseless methods for a controller. If using Doctrine, this should reside in the repository. If using Zend\Db, this should be placed in the data mapper. Basically, extract the `fetchSingle` and `fetchAll` from your controller and put it in a separate class.

Comment: @JurianSluiman I have submit my code above. Modeule, Controller and Model. The question now is how can my code work with your code.

Comment: Your model is a table gateway. Just replace my "Repository" with your model. Usually you don't call that class a model (rather a repository) but it does the same. My answer has the method `fetchAll()`, yours is named `getCategories()` but both do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a navigation element on your side, you can start with a custom view heler. The helper will load the categories and construct a navigation menu.

A view helper can look like this:

```php
namespace MyApp\View\Helper;

use MyApp\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Zend\Navigation\Navigation;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CategoryMenu
{
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(CategoryRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository
    }

    public function __invoke(array $options = array)
    {
        $categories = $this->repository->fetchAll();
        $container  = $this->buildNavigation($categories);
        $navigation = $this->getView()->navigation();

        return $navigation->menu()->renderMenu($container, $options);
    }

    private function buildNavigation(array $categories)
    {
        $pages = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $pages[] = [
                'label'  => $category->getName(),
                'route'  => 'categories/view',
                'params' => ['id' => $category->getId()]
            ];
        }

        return new Navigation($pages);
    }
}
```

This helper requires a repository (do **not** use `fetchSingle()` or `fetchAll()` in controllers, they are mapper / repository methods!). When you invoke the helper, it fetches all categories from the database, builds a navigation object and calls the navigation view helper to render it into a menu.

I am not writing all glueing parts down, but you require a decent repository so you can access the database and a factory for this view helper. Then register the view helper in your module configuration.

The `$options` from `__invoke()` are passed onto the menu helper, so you can apply options there (like, the ulClass, min/max depth etc). Usage: `<div><?= $this->categoryMenu([])?></div>`.

Note I tried to link all categories to a page, but I was missing that information from your question. I assume here the route `categories/view` exists and it requires a parameter `id` for the category id. Update the `buildNavigation()` method to suit it your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you aiming the best approach, your controllers shouldn't fetch anything from database. This is a service (better) data layer (best) job. You need to consume that service in controller while consuming fetch/fetchAll methods of the repository (data layer) in service.

When you move that fetch and fetchAll logic into dedicated classes as dedicated methods, you'll easily figure out how to reuse them and question becomes *"How can i inject my x service to my CategoryController?"*.

I suggest you focus on reading few articles on topics like [separating of concerns](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-objectorient/).

Comment: Thnx for your reply @foozy. I already seperated controller, modul and view. But now i want to make a new class Navigation which extends the categorycontroller class. How can i fixed that.